# playing videos inside frame tkinter python

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

Hi i am using python TKinter to play videos in a GUI that I already built. however, a new window pops out to play the video instead of playing it in the frame that i have already created. here's the coding to play the video

```
def openVideo():
        filename_=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select Video", filetypes=(("executables","*.mp4"),("all files","*.*")))
        #print (filename_)
        apps.append(filename_)
         
        net= cv2.dnn.readNet("D:/Downloads/vehicles/yolov3.weights", "D:/Downloads/vehicles/yolov3.cfg")
        classes=[]
        with open ("D:/Downloads/vehicles/coco.names","r") as f:
            classes= f.read().splitlines()

        cap=cv2.VideoCapture(filename_)

        while True:
            _, img=cap.read()
```

how do i make the video play inside a frame? heres the coding for the frame:

```
fcanvas= Frame(height = 560, width=800 , bd=3, highlightbackground='#595959', background='#595959', highlightthickness=1, cursor='hand2')
```

Comment: Could you please add the code part where you display the frames?

Comment: `fcanvas= Frame(height = 560, width=800 , bd=3, highlightbackground='#595959', background='#595959', highlightthickness=1, cursor='hand2') `


i just write this coding and the frame will appear in the window